# What is wrong with this React Context?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to get this to toggle the theme light and dark... the specifications require it to pass theme and toggleTheme. In the toggle component, onChange is set to toggleTheme. That part works, it's just setting the state that seems to work for one toggle but not any subsequent toggles (or toggling back).

Disclaimer: This is for a course on Coursera. The lab is not a graded lab. The answer is locked until I complete the lab though and I don't know what completing the lab means to achieve the requirements.

```
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react';

const ThemeContext = createContext(undefined);

export const ThemeProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const toggleTheme = (e) => {
        if (theme["theme"] === "dark") {
            setT({"theme":"light", toggleTheme});
        } else {
            setT({"theme":"dark", toggleTheme});
        }
    }
    const [theme, setTheme] = useState({
        theme: "dark",
        toggleTheme: () => toggleTheme
    });
    return <ThemeContext.Provider value={theme}>{children}</ThemeContext.Provider>;
}

export const useTheme = () => useContext(ThemeContext);
```

I've tried passing the theme and toggleTheme in as parameters, but it said toggleTheme wasn't a function. I'm expecting it to toggle the color scheme to go back and forth. Here is some more code:

Toggle Switch:

```
import "./Styles.css";
import { useTheme } from "../ThemeContext";

const Switch = () => {
  const { theme, toggleTheme } = useTheme();
  return (
    <label className="switch">
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        defaultChecked={theme === "light"}
        onChange={toggleTheme}
      />
      <span className="slider round" />
    </label>
  );
};

export default Switch;

Paragraph:

    
const Paragraph = ({ children }) => {
    const { theme } = useTheme();
    return (
        <p
            style={{
            color: theme === "light" ? "black" : "white",
            }}
         >
         {children}
         </p>
    );
};
```

Comment: ```setT({"theme":"light", toggleTheme});```, ```setT``` shouldn't be ```setTheme```?

Comment: I don't see `ThemeProvider` used anywhere

Answer (score 3):

There are few issues:

1. You have setT instead of setTheme
2. The value of the context has only the theme and doesn't include the setter.
3. You don't use ThemeProvider anywhere.
4. You need to put the `toggleTheme` function into context not state.

Your code should look like this:

```
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react';

const ThemeContext = createContext(undefined);

export const ThemeProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const toggleTheme = (e) => {
        if (theme["theme"] === "dark") {
            setTheme("light");
        } else {
            setTheme("dark");
        }
    }
    const [theme, setTheme] = useState("dark");
    return <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ theme, toggleTheme }}>{children}</ThemeContext.Provider>;
}

export const useTheme = () => useContext(ThemeContext);
```

and inside your app:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider>
      ...
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```